# Karatsuba Algorithm in Big O n^(lg3) proof by substitution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, substitution

Karatsuba Algorithm involves the recursion relation `T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n`.

By the recursion tree method, we can approximate the big O of `T` to be `O(nlog23)`

However, by the substitution method I am having trouble verifying the approximate result I found by the recursion tree method

I'll simply use `lg 3` to mean `log23`.

Substitution method:

```
Hypothesis -> T(n) <= cnlg 3 where c is a positive constant
Proof -> T(n) <= 3c(n/2)lg 3 + n
                  =  cnlg 3 + n
```

But step 2 of the proof shows that I cannot prove my hypothesis because of n term.

I modified step 2 of proof

```
T(n) <= cnlg 3 + nlg 3
      = (c+1)nlg 3
```

And later realized I had made a mistake because the hypothesis is not proven.

`T(n) <= cnlg 3` has to be proven, not `T(n) <= (c+1)nlg 3`

But the answer is `T(n)` is `O(nlg 3)`

Answer (score 2):

When using the substitution method, you sometimes have to strengthen the inductive hypothesis and guess a more complex form of the expression that upper-bounds the recurrence.

Try making a guess of the form T(n) ≤ c<sub>0</sub> n<sup>lg 3</sup> - c<sub>1</sub>n. Now that you are subtracting some term of the form c<sub>1</sub> n, you can probably make the recurrence work out by using some of the linear term to offset the n term added in later.

For example:

> T(n) ≤ 3T(n / 2) + n
>
> ≤ 3(c<sub>0</sub>(n/2)<sup>lg 3</sup> - c<sub>1</sub>(n/2)) + n
>
> = 3(c<sub>0</sub>(n/2)<sup>lg 3</sup>) - 3c<sub>1</sub>n/2 + n

Now, choose c<sub>1</sub> so that -3c<sub>1</sub>n/2 + n = -c<sub>1</sub>n. This solves to

> -3c<sub>1</sub>n/2 + n = -c<sub>1</sub>n
>
> -3c<sub>1</sub>/2 + 1 = -c<sub>1</sub>
>
> -3c<sub>1</sub> + 2 = -2c<sub>1</sub>
>
> 2 = c<sub>1</sub>

This choice of c<sub>1</sub> will then let you cancel out the +n term successfully, letting the induction work successfully.

Hope this helps!